# Finding polynomials that can be iterated to generate the field.

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

For a prime p and a field $\mathbb{Z}_p$,  is there support to find polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ that can be iterated to generate all of $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

As an example that such exist, let p = 251 and consider $f(x) = 3x^3 + 3x^2+x+39 \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$. You can iterate this polynomial with any $x_0 \in \mathbb{Z}_p$, i.e., $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$, and generate all of $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

I would appreciate any help identifying the theory about how such polynomials can be selected. Or even a topic / reference that gets me in the ballpark.

Comment: You know that any function $f:\Bbb{Z}_p \to \Bbb{Z}_p$ is realized with the polynomial $f = \sum_{a=0}^{p-1}f(a) \prod_{b \ne a} \frac{x-b}{a-b}$ and that as functions $g =f$ iff as polynomials $x^p-x |g-f$ ? From there we can contruct all the polynomials satisfying your problem for a given $p$. In general $f$ will be of degree $\le p-1$, that you found one of degree $3$ for $p = 251$ is probably quite exceptional. Asking for the polynomial of least degree given $p$ would be fun.

Comment: I'm not following. Might you have a reference that I could locate and examine?

Comment: Unless I am missing something, $x+1$ works well.

Comment: What is unclear to you ? Given any permutation $\sigma : \Bbb{Z}_p \to \Bbb{Z}_p$ there is a polynomial such that $f(\sigma(a)) = \sigma(a+1)$ which satisfies $\Bbb{Z}_p=\{ x_0,f(x_0),f(f(x_0)),\ldots \}$. Of course when I mentioned $\deg(f)$ I meant excluding those of degree $1$.

Comment: Or, to any $p$-cycle in $Sym(\Bbb{Z}_p)$ there exists a polynomial $f$ such that $f(a)=\sigma(a)$ for all $a$. As $a\mapsto\sigma(a)\mapsto\sigma^2(a)\cdots\mapsto\sigma^p(a)=a$ cycles through all the elements for any $a$, so do iterates of $f$.

Comment: Anyway, if reuns's formula is not clear, look up [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). There is (assuming a field as the playground) a polynomial of degree $\le d-1$ that has a prescribed value at selected $d$ points. Here the field is finite, so we can prescribe the value at all the points, i.e. $d=p$.

Comment: I can see that the formula (in reuns post) yields the identity permutation. But an adjustment of the constant terms can sift to any permutation - including those that iterate through the field as would a generator. I would guess that most of these are of order p-1. But the construction is where I'm not following; you are saying that to achieve equality with a polynomial g, it must be the case that $(x^p - x) | (g - f)$? Where did that come from?

Comment: I spoke with a friend. He said that my reply reflected that I was challenging the replies. That was not the intention. I'm in awe and grateful how you pulled this up so quickly! My questions are so I can discover the proof behind the ideas that you pointed out. I'm a novice in Abst. Algebra - had a year of it long ago. It's a struggle for me to even form the questions well. I'm still digesting in constructing actual polynomials to resolve my quest. There's a more interesting problem behind this problem. I may post in the next week so you can consider whether it interests you.